# Booting Issue in Ubuntu 18.04 external hard drive set up

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi, bootloader

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 on an external hard drive. The details of the hard drive are:
Storage: 500 GB
Type: SSD
Make: SanDisk

The installation happened seamlessly, but after I remove the live USB and restart the system, I am facing an issue.

I am seeing the Ubuntu drive option while I hit on the OS loader option (F12 key) and after I select to boot Ubuntu, its booting Windows 10 instead of Ubuntu. Here's the video of what is happening.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/YmDMvJWidwSGcvcb9

Here, when I open the drive, I see a EFI boot loader menu showing up on File Manager. I feel that there is some error with respect to EFI boot.

I am not able to figure out the fix for it. If someone can help me out with this, it would be a great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you want to use the same drive in other computers there's no reason to have an additional efi partition in it. The dual-boot works with the efi partition already in the internal drive and Ubuntu installed in the external drive (but you may have to use UEFI settings to boot Windows directly).

Answer (score 0):

The problem got fixed. The issue was being raised because, while installation, I was choosing Something else option for partitioning the Disk manually. I reinstalled the OS by selecting Erase Disk and Install and it worked seamlessly.